# Upgrade to facelets - Myfaces 2.0, Tomahawk, ajax4jsf - Facelets pages don't render

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, ajax4jsf, tomahawk

I migrated a jsf1 project to jsf2.
The webapp is based on Myfaces 2.1.8 , Tomahawk20-1.1.13 and ajax4jsf-1.1.1 - running on Tomcat 7. It all works well so I wanted to upgrade part of the pages to facelets and plug in Primefaces too.
The problem is that facelets pages do not render if I use jsf core tags - browser displays blank page, no errors in the logs either. 
If the page is pure xhtml it renders fine. I know that this happens if the Faces servlet does not work at all but with a mapping of *.jsf it should first look for the .xhtml pages, right?
Any help will be appreciated.

It seems that facelets and ajax4jsf cannot coexist.

Answer (score 0):

If your pages have a `.xhtml` extension your web.xml should contain something like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you have `*.jsf` as url-pattern and your pages have a `.xhtml` extension, it's obvious that the pages don't get rendered. In other words, the url-pattern must match the pages to be rendered.

Comment: I tried that too, still get the same problem. 
If I remove the ajax4jsf jar though, the facelets pages render.